# MongoServer changes in MongoDB 3.4?

Tags: mongodb, disconnect

I found out that in the newest version (3.4), there is no more class with the name of MongoServer. Anybody knows what is it called now? I need the Disconnect() method to be called.

Comment: in which driver?

Comment: same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37101435/mongo-server-class-not-present . See the new driver version http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoServer_Disconnect.htm "Normally there is no need to call this method so you should be sure to have a good reason to call it"

Comment: @alex driver 2.4.2. Well I take it there is no disconnect() method anymore?